# AWK matching fields between two files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm new with sh and AWK comand, I've been trying some commands with different options but didn't work :(

I've two files and i want to match the position 22,3 from the file1 with the string on the file2. If there is no match, I need to write the file1 line.

File1:

> /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/AAA
>     /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/BBB
>     /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/CCC
>     /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/DDD

File2:

> BBB
>     DDD

Result:

> /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/BBB
>     /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/DDD

I never wrote on this page but saved my ass a lot of times.
BIG THANKS!

Comment: Why `position 22,3` ? It looks like you want to match fifth field from file1, consider / as the delimiter, with the only field in file2

Comment: `been trying some commands`, put them in your post.

Comment: _If there is_ **no** _match, I need to_ **write the file1 line** Isn't the expected result the opposite (or is it just my flu)?

Comment: @JamesBrown shit, as you say i need the opposite result as I put on the result, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly you are looking for :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next} {n=0;for(i in a){if(substr($0,22,3)~i) { n=1}  } } n' file2 file1
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: TY! That works perfect. Is it posible to print the opposite like I put on my last comment?

Comment: Hmm, if you switch the places of `n=1` and `n=0` it probably works. Or in the end replace the `n` with `!n`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for the `substr` function in awk

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{arry[substr($0,22,3)]=$0;next}$0 in arry{print arry[$0]}' file1 file2
/batch/shared/TZ/TMP/BBB
/batch/shared/TZ/TMP/DDD
```

should do what you wish to do.

However there is an easier option, use the `/` as the delimiter

```
awk -v FS="/" 'NR==FNR{arry[$NF]=$0;next}$0 in arry{print arry[$0]}' file1 file2
```

Here `$NF` would give the last field in each record for the first file.

Comment: I'd imagine using `/` as a field sep and getting the last field would be more general and robust.

Comment: @123 : Same feeling here. Updated ;)

Comment: Also using the file the other way round would reduce complexity i.e `awk -F/ 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$NF in a' file2 file1`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$ awk '!(substr($0,22,3) in a){a[$0];next} 1' file2 file1
/batch/shared/TZ/TMP/BBB
/batch/shared/TZ/TMP/DDD
```

Walk-thru:

```
!(substr($0,22,3) in a)  # first read file2 with partial strings of file1 (BBB)
{                        # there won't be match until substr returns something so
    a[$0]                # put it in a and
    next                 # process next
} 
1                        # when substr returns a positive match, print it
```

If you in fact do need the opposite result set as discussed in the comments of the question:

```
$ awk 'NR>FNR && !(substr($0,22,3) in a) {print; next} {a[$0]}' file2 file1
/batch/shared/TZ/TMP/AAA
/batch/shared/TZ/TMP/CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank's you all!

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next} {n=0;for(i in a){if(substr($0,22,3)~i) {
n=1}  } } n' file2 file1  

awk -F/ 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$NF in a' file2 file1
```

These two results works for the question I put on my first comment. 
I did a fault,  I need the opposite result than the result i put:(

New result:

> /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/BBB
>   /batch/shared/TZ/TMP/DDD

Sorry for my English.

Big thanks!